# Prime factor visitation. Flipping states based on prime factors

Tags: python, arrays, binary, primes, flip

So I have a list of 1s and 0s:

[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

and a list of numbers: [3, 4, 15]

I have to find all the prime factors of those numbers, and flip the states in the first list that correspond to the prime factors of those numbers.

So for the above example:

numbers[0] = 3, prime factors are just 3

So after the states were changed, the array look like:

[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], so every (i + 1) % 3 == 0 positions were flipped

numbers[1] = 4, prime factors are just 2

So after the states were changed, the array look like:

[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

numbers[3] = 15, prime factors are just 3, 5

So after the states were changed, the array look like:

[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]

Heres what i have so far:

```
from collections import Counter

def prime_factors(num):
  i = 2
  factors = []
  while i * i < = num:
    if (num % i):
      i += 1
    else:
      num //= i
      factors.append(i)
  if (num > 1):
    factors.append(num)
  return list(set(factors))

def flip(states, numbers):
  factors = []

  for num in numbers:
    factors.extend(prime_factors(num))

  facotrs = Counter(factors)

  for key, val in factors.items():
    if val % 2:
      for i in range(len(states)):
        if ((i + 1) % factor == 0):
          states[i] = 1 if states[i] == 0 else 0
    
  return states
```

This works fine, but for large lists, it TLEs.

How do I fix this to make it faster?

Comment: What's the link to the original question?

Comment: There isnt one. this was on a hackerrank coding challange for a company. I got 13/15 test cases to pass, the last 2 exceeds time limit

Comment: Also, if this is an OA, you should know the constraints of the problem. What are those constraints?

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
   for i in range(len(states)):
      if ((i + 1) % factor == 0):
        states[i] = 1 if states[i] == 0 else 0
```

seems too elaborate. How about (untested!):

```
    for i in range(factor - 1, len(states), factor):
        states[i] = 1 - states[i]
```

? That is, jump directly to all only the indices `i` such that `i+1` is divisible by `factor`.

### Making factoring very fast

Here's suitable sieve code as mentioned in a comment. If the maximum possible number "is large", of course this is an absurd approach. But you haven't told us. If it's up to a few million, this goes fast.

```
# Return list `sf` such that sf[i] is the smallest prime
# factor of `i`, for 2 <= i <= maxn.
def sieve(maxn):
    from math import isqrt
    sf = list(range(maxn + 1))
    for i in range(4, len(sf), 2):
        sf[i] = 2
    for p in range(3, isqrt(maxn) + 1, 2):
        if sf[p] == p:
            for i in range(p * p, len(sf), p + p):
                if sf[i] == i:
                    sf[i] = p
    return sf
```

### The whole thing

Here's a whole program. Code for `sieve()` was already given. Once that's called, it never needs to be called again.

It's often the case that successfully completing timed "programming challenges" *crucially* relies on the stated input constraints. You were asked several times to tell us what they were, but to no avail. My educated guess is that they put a relatively low limit on the maximum number that needs to be factored. The program here exploits that. But if they didn't put limits on it, there's scant hope for "a fast" solution, because efficient factoring of truly large integers remains a difficult, open research problem.

The method here tries to balance the time and space needed for preprocessing against the time needed to factor. It may or may not be "the best" tradeoff, depending on the still-unknown-to-us input constraints. For example, if the maximum number is "quite" small, you could fully compute - and store - the unique prime factors for every possible number in advance (although a sieve method would remain the fastest easy way to do that).

```
# Return list of unique prime factors of n.
def upf(n, sf):
    result = []
    while n > 1:
        p = sf[n]
        result.append(p)
        n //= p
        while n % p == 0:
            n //= p
    return result

MAXN = 1_000_000
sf = sieve(MAXN)

def crunch(nums, bits, sf):
    from collections import defaultdict
    pcount = defaultdict(int)

    for num in nums:
        for p in upf(num, sf):
            pcount[p] += 1

    for p, count in pcount.items():
        if count & 1:
            for i in range(p - 1, len(bits), p):
                bits[i] = 1 - bits[i]

nums = [3, 4, 15]
bits =     [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
expected = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
crunch(nums, bits, sf)
assert bits == expected
```

Comment: This works, but it still has the time limit exceed issue

Comment: Well, thrashing at random blindly isn't all that much fun for us ;-) Need more info. For example, _maybe_ one of the input numbers is a large prime, and it's the factorization algorithm chewing up all the time by uselessly dividing by every integer through the floor of its square root. On & on. There are many possibilities - and many ways to try to address them.

Comment: Wait a second. How do you know the optimization written by @TimPeters still causes a TLE? You don't have the OA open while asking us to optimize your code, right?

Comment: No i did it earlier today. I believe the issue is somewhere in the loop. probably for a very large number input

Comment: That doesn't sound quite right. Companies almost always prevent you from accessing the original questions once you close the OA, let alone being able to see whether your code runs fast enough.

Comment: Please answer questions: how do you do know it TLEs? If you did this "earlier today", how is that possible? As @BrokenBenchmark also asked, what are the constraints you were given? Maximum number of integers, maximum size of integers, maximum list length? And what do _you_ mean by "large" in "large lists"?

Comment: I only see two possible bases for the claim that @TimPeters 's answer doesn't provide a speedup significant enough. Either 1.) you have some sort of benchmark to determine that it isn't fast enough, in which case you should have no problem giving us benchmarking code as well as time constraints; or 2.) you have the OA open right now, in contradiction to what you've just said.

Comment: Ok sorry i misspoke. I dont have it open. I believe it does not provide enough speed up, but no way to test it now, I am just wondering if there any any other optimizations in the above code that i missed other than @TimPeters's suggestion

Comment: Alright. I would add the constraints from the original question as an edit to your original post, and it would be best if you could benchmark your code (with and without the suggested optimization). Given the aforementioned ambiguities, the onus is now on you to show that there is a reasonable expectation of a TLE.

Comment: Since you won't answer the questions, I'm giving up. I'll leave you with one thing: use a procedure akin to the Sieve of Eratosthenes to create a list `sf` such that `sf[i]` is the smallest prime factor of `i`. This is a one-time cost, and will make factoring very efficient. But you need to know the maximum possible number in advance.

Comment: I added a whole program to make that suggestion concrete.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, val in factors.items():
    if val % 2:
      for i in range(len(states)):
        if ((i + 1) % factor == 0):
          states[i] = 1 if states[i] == 0 else 0
```

In the second for-loop, you don't need to start at `0` in `range(len(states))`. You can start with `factor-1`.

In `states[i] = 1 if states[i] == 0 else 0`,

you can replace this line with `XOR` operator:

`states[i] = states[i]^1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to optimize the prime number generator with the sieve of Eratosthenes. Should work withing a couple seconds for numbers less than 10<sup>7</sup>

```py
import math;

def sieve_primes(number):
    a = [True if n>=2 and n%2==1 or n==2 else False for n in range(number+1)];
    for x in range(3, (int)(math.sqrt(number))):
        if a[x]:
            for xx in range(x*x, number, x):
                a[xx] = False;
    primes = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i]:
            primes.append(i);
    return primes;
```

Also, you could avoid multiple calls to the prime generator by finding the biggest number that you'll need to factorize, generating primes for it and storing them for later lookup.